# Send data to Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, communication

I'm working on a program that is autostarting with windows. The program is a `windows-forms` application written in `C#`. When it gets started, it automatically hides itself and shows a tray icon. So it's only visible in tray, not in taskbar, not as a window.

Now I want somehow to send an ID (a simple int number) to the running windows form and the form should automatically show a messagebox with the recieved number.

Sending should be directly, not over a database or a textfile that is watched.

Is there a way to send data to a open windows form?

Any help apreciated :)

Comment: From a different process?  If it's in the same process, just create a property or method in the form class that accepts your ID.

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net I wonder?

Comment: You will want to host a WCF service within your Windows Form, and then send data to it, probably in the form of XML - [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows) may help

Comment: What is sending the int? A program you wrote?

Comment: The sending program is not written yet. It can be a program in any form (exe, vbs, bat,...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about named pipes?

They are persistent, and easily accessible.
Here's a blog post detailing both the 2.0 and 3.5 implementations:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/dotnet-35-adds-named-pipes-support

Comment: Thank you, this is working great. What also helped me is the source from [here](http://dzaebel.net/NamedPipes.htm)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the standard Windows APIs `SendMessage` (synchronous) or `PostMessage` (asynchronous / send and forget). To use these APIs you must know the handle of the Windows Form / application main form.

there are also other ways but this might be by far the simplest and would work from same or other process and is very lightweight for an integer only like you need to pass.

Comment: That was my first attempt and worked. But the program has to be minimized in tray and in that state the MainWindowHandle is 0 so I was not able to send something to it. Is this even possible when it is minimized and not visible?